# XGBoost - Feature selection using XGBRegressor

Tags: python, xgboost

I am trying to perform features selection (for regression tasks) by `XGBRegressor()`.

More precisely, I would like to know:

- If there is something like the method
  `feature_importances_`, utilized with `XGBClassifier`, which I could use for regression.
- If the XGBoost's method `plot_importance()` is reliable when it is used with `XGBRegressor()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have solved this issue by:

`model.booster().get_score(importance_type='weight')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution (Xnames refers to the feature names):

```
def xgb_feature_importance(model_xgb, fnames=None):
    b = model_xgb.booster()
    fs = b.get_fscore()
    all_features = [fs.get(f, 0.) for f in b.feature_names]
    all_features = np.array(all_features, dtype=np.float32)
    all_features_imp = all_features / all_features.sum()
    if fnames is not None:
        return pd.DataFrame({'X':fnames, 'IMP': all_features_imp})
    else:
        return all_features_imp
```